# Reasonable limit on SVG for website background, or ideas as to why this is not loading otherwise?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm making the assumption that the following is the result of the image's size:

I have two 10MB SVG (yes, they're huge), given to me by a graphic designer, that are supposed to act as background images for a client's landing page. It is a rather complex graphic that I don't think is suitable for SVG. I have tried to call them in a variety of ways without success, and have several (very small) svg images that render without issue, called into the DOM via:

```
<img id="logoImg" src="SvgLogo.svg" alt="OurLogo">
```

I imagine having a 10MB image is problematic for other reasons (though I haven't gzip'd); however, does anyone have any ideas if the size is the root of my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10MB svg is definitely a problem.

If you don't need transparency .gif is a good compressible format.

If you need transparency you can shoot for .png but will be slightly bigger than gif.

Also when you export; make sure the correct size will fit on the website. Don't use width and height in the image tag.

If you go png then you can use a program like pngcrush

Comment: Yea, that's what I was thinking. Got the graphics guy to send me over some .png images so I could have transparency. They came in at around 700KB a piece, so SVG was definitely the wrong format. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What did the designer use to create the SVGs? Most editors (especially Illustrator) add a lot of extra cruft to the SVGs that can be removed to make it a lot smaller.  Plus you can gzip the SVG to reduce it even more. I would be surprised if you couldn't get it down to a similar size as the PNG.